# Twilio rest api error code 21612

Tags: c#, twilio, mms

When I attempt to send an image file using the Twilio.SendMessage Rest API call, I get the error : Code 21612 - The 'To' phone number is not currently reachable via SMS or MMS.

Here is the code I use:

```
var message = twilio.SendMessage(fromPhone, phone, "a message for you", new string[] {"http://website.com/images/folder/pic.jpg"});
```

This phone number works fine for text messages. I checked with my carrier, and my plan includes "picture Messaging" as well. So I am questioning the validity of the error message. Is there something else I need to check or do to get this to work?

Comment: I got a similar error when using Google Voice on a different provider, although it worked on Twilio.

Comment: The error message actually reads this: "The 'To' phone number: <toPhone>, is not currently reachable using the 'From' phone number: <fromPhone> via MMS.". So this could be an issue with either number?

Comment: Does it work for other numbers? Or just this recipient?

Comment: Twilio MMS only works from US and Canadian Twilio numbers right now. Are you sending from a number from either of those countries? It also only sends proper MMS messages to US/Canadian recipients, so are you sending to either of those countries? You can send MMS internationally (from a US/Canadian Twilio number), but the picture would get replaced with a short URL to the image file.

Comment: I tried using another number and get the same error. Both the numbers are here in the US.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I used Alphanumeric sender id (ex: TWILLIO) when sending messages. So USA doesn't support alphanumeric sender ids. You can see the list of countries support or need to be pre-registered to support alphanumeric sender id. [The list](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID)

[Error code explanation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21612)